# How to fix LineageOS 18.1 bootloop on Sony Xperia XZ3?

Tags: boot-loop, lineageos, sony-xperia

I installed LineageOS 18.1 following [official guide](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/akatsuki/install) and also installed MindTheGapps. Now I am stuck in infinite loop of booting: LineageOS logo flashes for few seconds and phone reboots same thing happens over and over again. How can I fix this? I tried reinstalling the LineageOS again, but same thing happens.

[image]

Comment: Though this issue is hopefully no longer there: have you tried without installing MindTheGapps? Could well be that package is the culprit. If all is fine without that, take a closer look if you maybe picked the wrong version of it (version of GApps must match Android version).

Comment: I tried without and with it still doesn't boot.

Comment: Was worth a try, and at least narrows things down. You performed a complete wipe before flashing, I assume – so I'm out of ideas then, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the SD card when, that will stop the bootloop. When you've booted up again, insert the SD card and continue as usual :)

Comment: I have no SD card inserted into this phone.